# Python: Regex to remove zeros preceded by letters?

Tags: python, regex

Having a bit of trouble coming up with a regex statement for the following room numbers:

```
C001B --> C1B //remove "leading" zeros after first set of letters
C100B --> C100B
CB001B --> CB1B //remove "leading" zeros after first set of letters
001B --> 1B //remove leading zeros
```

Essentially, remove all zeros which is not preceded by a numeral?

Comment: re.sub("^0+","",number), but this doesn't solve the problem of numbers with a letter preceeding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to match such zeros you could use a negative lookbehind, such as `(?<![^a-zA-Z])`, to ensure that the matched area is not preceded by anything but a letter. By inserting this before your match, it will ensure that whatever comes immediately before doesn't match the pattern contained, here `[^a-zA-Z]`, which also counts for matches at the very beginning of a line.

```
re.sub("(?<![^a-zA-Z])0+","",number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all patterns like `'ABC000'`, `'000'`, and eliminate the `'0'`s.

```
return re.sub( "([^0-9]+|^)0+", r'\1', raw )
```